# Percolation Textbook Recommendation

Tags: analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, statistical-mechanics, percolation

I was wondering if someone could recommend a Percolation textbook for undergraduates.  I have looked at Percolation by Grimmett and it seems quite dense.  I was looking for a book that I could self-study from with a decent amount of explanation.  As far as background, I have taken a graduate course in measure theory and the undergraduate analysis sequence. Thanks.

Comment: what texts did you use for these courses?

Comment: Folland Measure Theory and Rudin PMA for analysis

Answer (score 2):

I think for your background, the [notes](http://www.ihes.fr/~duminil/publi/2017percolation.pdf) of Hugo Duminil-Copin would be great. They are just 30 pages long but it is a decent amount of exposition and it has many exercises that can help you develop by yourself. Some proofs are a bit short, but I think they use a nice amount of intuition for those who are starting in the area.

Comment: Hi Kernel Thanks for the response.  These look good, is there also a textbook that you recommend

Comment: I think the main textbook references are Grimmet and Bollobás, but both are quite dense. I would stick to lecture notes or article reviews.

Answer (score 1):

From what I remember, [Bollobas and Riordan book](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/percolation/75F54872F9FE1DFDB2EE95B37E0BC382#fndtn-information) is much more accessible than Grimmett. Hopefully it will suit your needs (or those of the MSE readers who arrived here).